# How to delete columns while looping over data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a number of data frames that all have a column with the same name; and I would like to loop over all the data frames to delete the column.

As an example :

```
> df1
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2

> df2
  a c
1 1 3
2 1 3
3 1 3
```

I also have a list of all the data frame names :

```
> df.list
[[1]]
[1] "df1"

[[2]]
[1] "df2"
```

If I do `df1$a<-NULL`, column `a` is deleted.

I would like to delete column `a` in both dfs, this is what I tried :

```
library(dplyr)

make.null<-function(x) {
        x<-NULL
      }

lapply(df.list, function(x) {
      get(x) %>% select(starts_with("a")) %>% make.null()

       })
```

I also tried :

```
 lapply(df.list, function(x) {
      get(x) %>% select(-starts_with("a"))

       })
```

The console output from the last example is

```
[[1]]
  b
1 2
2 2
3 2

[[2]]
  c
1 3
2 3
3 3
```

but the data frames still have `a` as a column :

```
 > df1
  a b
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 1 2
```

So, **how could I get the column to be deleted in all the data frames from the list ?**

Comment: You have to assign the variables. Currently all you're doing is selecting.

Comment: You need to assign it back to your list. An alternative that does not need an external package can be: `lapply(df.list, function(i){i['a'] <- NULL; i})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to tidyverse, here is an example using lapply and select

```
library(tidyverse)

list_1 <- lapply(1:3, function(i)(tibble(a = sample(1000),
       c = sample(1000)))) ##Creates list of data frames

new_list <- lapply(list_1, function(i) i %>% select(-c)) ##loops through and remove c variable
new_list


##Using a for loop (not as efficient)
new_list2 <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(list_1)){
  new_list2[[i]] <- list_1[[i]] %>% select(-c)
}

new_list2
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something but this doesn't delete the columns like `df$a<-NULL` would, instead it creates 

    summary(new.list)
         Length Class      Mode
    [1,] 1      data.frame list
    [2,] 1      data.frame list

So I guess I should "extract" the 2 data frames and replace my original `df1` and `df2` by these ?

Comment: The solution creates a new list with data frames that do not have the variable "c". If you don't want to create a new object you can simply use the same name for a new object and use lapply

Comment: Thanks, solved now ! So it seems the main problem was that I was using a list of character names of data frames instead of a list of the data frames.

Answer (score 0):

In a tidyverse and purrr style,

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> 载入程辑包：'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose
df1 <- 
    data.table(a=rep(1,3),b=2)
df2 <- 
    data.table(a=rep(1,3),c=3)
list_tbl <- 
    list(df1,df2) %>% 
    map(~select(.,-a))
    # this is mapping function like loops
list_tbl
#> [[1]]
#>    b
#> 1: 2
#> 2: 2
#> 3: 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    c
#> 1: 3
#> 2: 3
#> 3: 3
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>